# Share greasemonkey script and database between Windows and Android Firefox

Tags: android, firefox, greasemonkey

I've been using a homemade greasemonkey scripts for ages on my laptop Firefox. It includes storing data with GM.setValue.

Now I just bought an Android tablet, and would like to be able to use this script and update the values, whereas I'm using the laptop or the tablet.

Hoped that Firefox Sync would handle that, but not even the scripts are synced.

I thought of synchronizing the script dans db files (Google drive, dropbox, whatever), but I realized that since the v4, the db that used to be in gm_scripts is gone, and I have no idea where Greasemonkey stores either the scripts or their associated database now.

I'm looking for anything that might make it work.

1) Is there a way to handle that with Firefox Sync ?

2) Would an alternative (Tampermonkey, Violentmonkey, ?) handle that better ?

3) Where can I find the scripts/database in the new Greasemonkey system ?

4) Could I synchronize them via Google drive ? (There seem to be some hacks to sync a file between machines)

5) Would there be a simple, free alternative that would allow me to synchronize a very small file between machines ?

===============================================
Update on this:

I tried TamperMonkey instead, it has a sync feature but even if it seems ok on different laptops or my phone, the syncing is random at best on the tablet.

Also realized that only scripts are synced, and not their data. The script almost never changes, but the data is updated several times a day, so not really a solution anyway.

Data doesn't exist anymore in a readable file format, so no luck either on syncing the data file externally.

TamperMonkey has also an import/export feature, this does take the data into account. So the best I can do for now is thinking about exporting then importing every time I switch device. Not ideal so still in search of a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclusion:
1-2) I switched to TamperMonkey where I could easily up/download scripts from Google Drive (or other).

3-4-5) New browser extensions architecture means that you basically can't access the data on file system

The only solution is to store/retrieve data elsewhere, not with the GM methods. I stored mine in an airtable base, because it offers a pretty easy to use API that can be called from user scripts.

Answer (score 0):

> [storage.sync](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/sync)
>
> Represents the sync storage area. Items in sync storage are synced by
>   the browser, and are available across all instances of that browser
>   that the user is logged into (e.g. via Firefox sync, or a Google
>   account), across different devices.

There are limitations with sync.

- Sync requires login
- Up to 100kb can be synced and more than that fails
- Storage sync usually syncs the entire extension storage and in case of user-script managers, they are often larger than 100kb as they include the user-scripts as well
- Data is stored elsewhere (not on your computer) which can have security/privacy concerns
- Storage read/write requires internet access and longer times due to remote data storage
- Extension must have the sync option

> 1) Is there a way to handle that with Firefox Sync ?

Yes but depends on aforementioned. While [Firefox sync](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox/sync) doesn't appear to have the 100kb limit, syncing the entire Firefox takes longer ([How do I set up Sync on my computer?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-sync-my-computer)).

> 2) Would an alternative (Tampermonkey, Violentmonkey, ?) handle that better ?

Greasemonkey: No sync feature
Tampermonkey: Sync to Dropbox, Google Drive, or a WebDAV service
Violentmonkey: Sync to Dropbox, OneDrive, Google Drive, or a WebDAV service
Firemonkey: No sync feature

TM/VM 3rd party storage sync allows storage of more than 100KB. However, using 3rd party storage allows 3rd party tracking which is a privacy consideration. The storage read/write operation is also a lot slower.

> 3) Where can I find the scripts/database in the new Greasemonkey system ?

Since Firefox 57, extensions can not save files to the HD and the only storage area is the extension storage which is not accessible as before.

> 4) Could I synchronize them via Google drive ? (There seem to be some hacks to sync a file between machines)

Refer to above

> 5) Would there be a simple, free alternative that would allow me to synchronize a very small file between machines ?

That depends on the set-up and how often data is changed.

For example, if data is not often changed, especially if the data privacy is imperative, there is the backup export/import option (script + data). Therefore, the extension data can be saved to a USB flash drive and loaded anywhere (suitable for shared environment).

Comment: Related to 3), when you say "not accessible", does it mean there is no way to read it, copy it, even find it on the disk ?

Comment: As for 5) the use is to keep track of what I've read/no read/do not want to read/store for later on different websites.
Data is small (basically url as the name, an int as the value), but changes several times a day. So import/export would be very bothersome.

Comment: @user2739975 AFAIK, Storage is in sqlite for all and not individual files. Also read: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data

If data is small, basic extension storage sync should be fine. Check with script managers to see if they can provide it.

Comment: That's what I didn't find. I know where my profile is (at least on Windows), I've been saving it and moving it from machine to machine for over 15 years. (Though I don't know where it is on Android as /profilemanager is not available).
And I searched for values that should be in my db in all of the profile files and could not find it. Some extension have at least a folder with their name, greasemonkey doesn't. No script name found either.

Comment: @user2739975  for example: C:\Users\.....\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\.......default\storage\default
I have no idea about Android and I doubt if that is possible to access it the same way as computer.